# How can I integrate MoneyBookers with an ASP.NET application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, payment-gateway

I have website developer using ASP.NET. It is done from scratch, with no Cart Shop System. I need to integrate it with my Payment Gateway Account.

Do you know of a module (DLL) for that integration?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at these article:

http://wyday.com/blog/2011/automate-moneybookers-skrill-using-status_url-ipn-php-asp-net/

Here is the Skrill (Moneybookers) manual:
https://www.moneybookers.com/app/help.pl?s=m_manual

Regards